# Disable time change in Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I live a few miles from the border of a time zone change and so I live in one time zone and do everything else in another.

I translate the time difference in my head and have been doing this for years. To reduce confusion, I disable the time zone change on my phone and leave it set to EST.

When I use Google calendar at home (EST time zone), I put all my appointments in their native timezone: CEN.

When so get to the appointment, my calendar changes the time zone for me which leads to a lot of confusion as to when the appointment really is.

I read that Google has this feature to make travel easy, and I admit if I were to be traveling across the country, I would love it. However, it makes living on the border of a time zone very difficult as I’m not sure which time zone it’s picking up.

Is there a way to disable the time zone change in Google Calendar so that when I put a time in as 7am central, it stays as 7am no matter where I am?